# How to define graph connections (source, destination) from a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, graph

I have a list [a, b, c, d, e] from which I want to generate a graph by defining (*source, destination*) nodes. The number of connections is variable, n. For example, with n=2 I would like to return

a b 
a c 
b c 
b d 
c d 
c e 
d e

Likewise, if n=3, I want to return

a b 
a c 
a d 
b c 
b d 
b e 
c d 
c e 
d e

For the n=2 case, I can get what I need but the arbitrary n-value is tripping me up.

```
my_list = ['a','b','c','d','e']
n = 2

for i in range(len(my_list)-(n-1)):
    j = 0
    for j in range(1,n+1,1):
        if (i == (len(my_list)-(n-1)-1)):
            print(my_list[i], my_list[i+j])
            break
        else:
            print(my_list[i], my_list[i+j])
            j +=1
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

From a colleague:

```
def generatePairings(list="", n=2):
     l = len(list)
     for i in range(l):
         for j in range(1,(n+1)):
             if (i+j<l):
                 print(list[i],list[i+j])

list = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
generatePairings(list,2)
```